# How to cancel an activity launched via rememberLauncherForActivityResult?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

In my composable function, I am using this code to register an activity launcher:

```
val intentLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
    contract = ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
) {
    // handle result
}
```

Which is then being launched via:

```
intentLauncher.launch(someIntent)
```

How can I cancel or terminate this activity, once it has been launched?

With `startActivityForResult()`, you can pass a request-code, which can then be used to cancel the activity with `activity.finishActivity(req_code)`. But with `rememberLauncherForActivityResult` there is no option to pass a request-code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to pass a request-code to the intent launcher, since it uses `ActivityResultRegistry` under the hood, which generates a random request-code, and does not expose it publicly.

You can cancel the activity, by "restarting" the parent activity with a flag:

```
val intent = Intent(this, this.javaClass).apply {
    flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT
}
startActivity(intent)
```

This brings the parent to the forground, which causes the `intentLauncher` to resolve immediately.